# Estimating the size of a population. Is the method employed valid?

Tags: sampling, small-sample, methodology, survey-sampling, capture-mark-recapture

**Context:** in North America there has been a Drug Overdose Epidemic for several years. In my own municipality, more people have died of overdose than of COVID during the pandemic.

My workplace (a non for profit) is trying to estimate the number of people $N$ who use safe drug sites. They define $N$ as follows: "$N$ is the number of people who use these safe-sites on any given day." (This definition was provided by social-scientists and it sounds like an average.) We are trying to convince some wealthy people to donate money for this cause and we want to convince them the current *methodology* (employed by government run agency) is innapropriate and the estimates are not very good indeed. Now, admittedly, this is what bureucracy of my work place wants, *I just want to understand the flaws of the methodology they use.*

**Methodology:**

1. On *one* given day, a group of dozens of volunteers go to all *known* safe drug sites and for that day they talk with everyone *that looks like a drug user* (whatever this means - what a drug user *is* is not defined in the manual).
2. They break the ice and try talking to the potential user, offering tokens or gifts to make them feel more comfortable. Once the presumed user is comfortable, they are invited to participate and answer the survey. They are asked all sorts of demographic questions (over a hundred of them, yikes!) Including drug use. There is a lot of partial answering (unsurprisingly) but the drug use, age, race, etc, are at the very beginning so those are complete.
3. They report $N$ to be the number of people who accepted to participate in the survey and stated they were drug users (usually, these two numbers differ by a handful, i.e. <5).

Now, I am no epidemiologist nor ecologist but this method for estimating $N$ sounds quite flawed. This would be my very first time tackling a problem like this, so I am very new to this particular type of modelling. In my impression the survey mechanism can, at most, estimate a *lower bound on the number of people using the drug site on the given day* and that is it.

> Is this estimate of $N$ any good? What critisisms of $N$ are possible? And do you know of any similar work where I could read or direct myself to better understand how to estimate $N$ in a social context like this?

I know this question is vague but I am not even sure what is the probabilistic model assumed behind the scenes. I thought of a Poisson process recording counts over time where the rate $\lambda$ (which is the expected number of counts in a given day) is unknown, $\lambda$ can be taken as an estimate of $N$ and what *is* recorded is a sample of size 1 of $\lambda.$

I thought a capture-recapture method would be better: one day, go to all sites, and do what they did on a randomly selected time. A couple months later do the same, and count the number of repeated people (in the survey you ask for name and other descrpitions that allow to identify people). But again, I am not at all familiar with surveying or capture-recapture methodology.